# Create a clock (datatype/md5sum) for slam_gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have managed to do teleoperation, laser scan as well as passing tf to the slam_gmapping node. (As shown in the rxgraph below)

[image description http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/missing_clock_md5sum.png](http://i1214.photobucket.com/albums/cc484/torresho/missing_clock_md5sum.png)

The only thing that is missing now is the "/clock" topic which has a md5sum datatype.

Question:

1. How to create a clock to use slam_gmapping on lego nxt instead of pr2?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30258/create-a-clock-(datatype/md5sum)-for-slam_gmapping/) by [Torres](https://answers.ros.org/users/2035/torres/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why do you need the clock topic? It is only used when the use_sim_time parameter is set to true, otherwise your computer's clock is used. You can find more information [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Clock).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0